# ebay getOrders API

Tags: ebay-api

I am building a .net service to getOrders from ebay. my service runs fine, however I dont know how should I handle data.

For example I am using CreateTimeTo and CreateTimeFrom Filter to return orders from past 24 hours. I save them into my database, now some orders return no Address info.

My question is, Whats the best way to hadnle/update already imported orders into my database. Say for example order imported into my system wa without shiping info, and customer completed shipping info after a week, how would I update that order in my system?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely use modtimefrom modtimeto filter. Ih this way you can get all order that have been modiefied in last "x interval". This way you will get either new orders and modified (checkout complete - paid - shipped) and so on. My favourite filter anyway is  NumberOfDays. This one acts as ModTimeFrom/ModTimeTo but is way more simple and you don't have to deal with dates.

An order without address means buyer has not completed checkout (no payment selected so no shipping address as well yet).

Once buyer completes checkout or order is mark as paid the entire address will be avaible.

You can get buyer default address shipping by using call GetSellerTransaction

I hope i understood your question and to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I agree using numberofDays is a good of doing things, however the problem is my VB.NET ebay Application does not have numberofdays property. I am Getting all the Orders from last 24 hours, then I run another job which select's ALL THE ACTIVE orders from my database and I query only those orders to see if their checkout has completed,if completed i grab the new info and change the order address. another issue is getting paypal ExternalID info, sometimes i comes blank, i am relying on paypal IPN service to tackle this issue.

Comment: Are you using an application already coded and you don't have source? Or did you compile the application by your self? Your solution is still good though but you have to make a lot more calls to retrieve data you need to update orders. Do you only have time filter for CreateTime?

Comment: I have source code, I was talking about eBay DLL's provided for .net, for some reason eBay totally ignored numberOfDays property within their compiled DLL's. Number of Calls is pretty much the Same, I make a array of all Active Orders and then post them to eBay in one shot. and I query Active Orders only couple of times a day VS getOrders Call (which I do more frequently).